# How to send props and methods between components?

Tags: reactjs

[image]

Hi guys, I'm trying to code little app. I am trainee programmer. I need help to understand how to use props on my app. I'm currently using one component from CodePen and I fetched the data from jsonplaceholder. But I don't know how to pass props between this component and App.js. It was no problem with easier components but here is lot of methods and events. With this tagged input I want to add or delete items.

```
import React from "react";

import StateFullComponent from "./components/StateFullComponent";
import StatelessComponent from "./components/StatelessComponent";
import TagInput from "./components/TagInput";

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <StatelessComponent
        props1={"String"}
        props2={1}
        props3={true}
        props4={JSON.stringify({ value: "value", key: 1 })}
      />
      <StateFullComponent items={["apple", "orrange", "pear", "male"]} />
      <TagInput />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class TagInput extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      users: [],
      focused: false,
      input: ""
    };

    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
    this.handleInputKeyDown = this.handleInputKeyDown.bind(this);
    this.handleRemoveItem = this.handleRemoveItem.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
      .then(response => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(result => {
        this.setState({
          users: result
        });
      });
  }

  add() {
    let value = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
    let users = this.state.users;
    users.push(value);
    this.setState({ users: users });
  }

  handleInputChange(evt) {
    this.setState({ input: evt.target.value });
  }

  handleInputKeyDown(evt) {
    if (evt.keyCode === 13) {
      const { value } = evt.target;

      this.setState(state => ({
        users: [...state.users, value],
        input: ""
      }));
    }

    if (
      this.state.users.length &&
      evt.keyCode === 8 &&
      !this.state.input.length
    ) {
      this.setState(state => ({
        users: state.users.slice(0, state.users.length - 1)
      }));
    }
  }

  handleRemoveItem(index) {
    return () => {
      this.setState(state => ({
        users: state.users.filter((user, i) => i !== index)
      }));
    };
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.props, ":::::::::::");

    const { users } = this.state;

    const userId = users.map((user, id) => <li key={id}>{user.name}</li>);
    const styles = {
      container: {
        border: "1px solid #ddd",
        padding: "5px",
        borderRadius: "5px"
      },

      items: {
        display: "inline-block",
        padding: "2px",
        border: "1px solid blue",
        fontFamily: "Helvetica, sans-serif",
        borderRadius: "5px",
        marginRight: "5px",
        cursor: "pointer"
      },

      input: {
        outline: "none",
        border: "none",
        fontSize: "14px",
        fontFamily: "Helvetica, sans-serif"
      }
    };

    return (
      /*  <div>
        <ul>{userId}</ul>
        <button onClick={this.handleRemoveItem().bind(this)}>add</button>
      </div> */

      <label>
        <ul style={styles.container}>
          {this.state.users.map((user, i) => (
            <li
              key={i}
              style={styles.users}
              onClick={this.handleRemoveItem(i).bind(this)}
            >
              {user}
              <span>(x)</span>
            </li>
          ))}
          <input
            style={styles.input}
            value={this.state.input}
            onChange={this.handleInputChange.bind(this)}
            onKeyDown={this.handleInputKeyDown.bind(this)}
          />
        </ul>
      </label>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your objectives.  Are you wanting the `App` component to manage data passed to `TagInput` component as props?  Are you wanting `TagInput` component to update the `App` component upon adding/removing data?  Or something else?

Comment: This specific error you get is because you try to render a user object. React does not know how to render those object, so they throw an error. Try changing your `{user}` to something like `{user.name}` (in your `render` function).

Comment: I want the App component to manage data passed to TagInput component as props. But maybe o would want both ways.

Comment: If you want App to manage the data, it will have to be a class-based component to hold a state object.  You would then move the componentDidMount method from TagInput to App and pass the fetched data you want TagInput to have as a prop (or set of props).  If you then want TagInput to be able to communicate back up to the App component, you could define a function in App that receives event/data and pass it to TagInput as a prop.  TagInput could then call the function passed as a prop when communication needs to go back to App.

Answer (score 1):

In your `componentDidMount` you are fetching data, and getting back an array of objects, and setting the state value `users` to the array of objects. That's all good and exactly what you should be doing.

The problem is in the `render` method when you are looping through the array of users. Remember that each `user` in the array is an object. Look at the jsx you have within the `li` element. You are rendering the `user` object, and an object is an invalid react child. Instead, you need to render the particular fields from the object.

Example, if the object contains a `name` field, and an `email` field, render `{user.name}` or `{user.email}`. That way you can render the particular fields of data from the user object.

```
<li
  key={i}
  style={styles.users}
  onClick={this.handleRemoveItem(i).bind(this)}
>
    Name: {user.name}
    Email: {user.email}
    Id: {user.id}
    <span>(x)</span>
</li>
```

It seems you may still have some questions about passing props to a component. This only addresses the particular error you are seeing. If you still have questions let me know.